# Joint for physical gun slider?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to make it so when I fire my gun the slider shoots back and then comes forward like a real gun. However I don't know how I should start because I can't find any relevant information on Google and I don't know what to search. All I need is the logic behind how to do it, I can code it myself.

Comment: what do you mean 'slider'? not a UI slider? whatever you do, a joint doesn't sound right as it will unnecesarily involve physics, you can just keyframe an animation and run it when neede

Comment: No I need it to be physical for a VR game I'm making. I just want to lock the slider position to move back and forth on the X axis on the gun and adjust axis relative to the gun as well.

Comment: still sounds like a job for an animation clip

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with zambari.
Just create an animation and play it when your guns gets fired.

Edit:

Since you are talking about 3D, you could either

- move the pivot of the object to the point where the trigger would be attached. This way, all you need to do is change the objects rotation for the animation.
- use joints

Comment: No I need it to be physical for a VR game I'm making. I just want to lock the slider position to move back and forth on the X axis on the gun and adjust axis relative to the gun as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tool for VR guns with interactable parts. I HIGHLY recommend looking at this to ANYONE making a VR game
https://github.com/Oyshoboy/weaponReloadVR